# BytesIO stream image is blank when uploading SimpleUploadedFile

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

On my model save method I want to generate an avatar and upload to a `ImageField` (self.avatar).

The code below runs but the image it uploads is blank when I view it. I've tested the generator actually works by saving directly to disk without `BytesIO` stream i.e. `image.save("test.jpeg", format=filetype, optimize=True)` and this works. So, the issue appears to be with how am using `BytesIO` and `SimpleUploadedFile`.

**Save  method**

```
from .generate_avatar import Avatar
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

avatar = Avatar.generate(128, self.display_name, "JPEG")
self.avatar = SimpleUploadedFile("temp.jpeg", avatar.read1(0))
```

**Generate Method**

```
def generate(cls, size, string, filetype="JPEG"):
        """
            Generates a squared avatar with random background color.

            :param size: size of the avatar, in pixels
            :param string: string to be used to print text and seed the random
            :param filetype: the file format of the image (i.e. JPEG, PNG)
        """
        render_size = max(size, Avatar.MIN_RENDER_SIZE)
        image = Image.new('RGB', (render_size, render_size),
                          cls._background_color(string))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        font = cls._font(render_size)
        text = cls._text(string)
        draw.text(cls._text_position(render_size, text, font),
                  text,
                  fill=cls.FONT_COLOR,
                  font=font)
        stream = BytesIO()
        image = image.resize((size, size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(stream, format=filetype, optimize=True)
        return stream
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset file position. Otherwise file position will be at the end of the file; Reading from there will return empty byte string.

```
avatar = Avatar.generate(128, self.display_name, "JPEG")
avatar.seek(0) # <---
self.avatar = SimpleUploadedFile("temp.jpeg", avatar.read())
```

Comment: Dam it! I knew that too! I assumed thats what ``read1(0)`` did. Thats worked. thank you.